# Use regex and python to arrange text file output regex.sub

Tags: python, regex, file, text

```
import re
import fileinput
import re

#regex used
#result = re.split('(?<=\S)[^-][ ](?=[a-zA-Z0-9])', line)
```

<---- this wrote on multiple lines but with one character missing on many lines and not very correct so I searched a lot and had to ad the "$" like below:

`result = re.split('(?<=\S$)[^-][ ](?=[a-zA-Z0-9])', line)`   <---- this makes a very good result but now I have some words sticked together that were not separted, I know the letters that precede a capital letter
for example "*****J" I need to have "***** J" and then to get back the letters that are like Sentence1 Sentence2 Sentence2 on newlines each and then I am done ! I am having trouble using re.sub, and then putting
all on new lines like I want to final output.

```
line = "WordsAreStickedTogetherHereIneedOneSpaceBetweeeThem"

result = re.split('(?<=\S$)[^-][ ](?=[a-zA-Z0-9])', line)

final_result = re.sub('dM','d M',result)
final_result = re.sub('dJ','d J',result)

for elem in final_result:
        print elem


ERRROR:

$python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 22, in <module>
    final_result = re.sub('dC','d C',result)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py", line 155, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: I don't see a clear problem statement.  One problem I _do_ see is that you're trying to use lookarounds with `re.split`.  You can't do that, so I would suggest adding some sample data which explains the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to transform `WordsAreSticked` to `Words Are Sticked`?

Comment: Yes @cglacet but I know the exact sequence of letters that precedes an Upper Case letter that needs to make a space (not uppercase followed by lowercase ), Sequence" "in between and then I need to write on newlines. So it is SequenceOfLettersUPPERCASE must be sequenceofletter" " UPPERCASE" this just to create the space between the words that are not separated and then write on newlines sequences like Name1 - Adress1 newline Name2 - Adress2  etc. (think aboout it like Adress1 has two words sticked together" re.finditer wants a string, can I convert my results=re.split back to a string? How?

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to split words (a word is an uppercase letter followed by lowercase letters), then you can simply use [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```py
line = "WordsAreStickedTogetherHereINeedOneSpaceBetweeeThem"
matches = re.finditer("[A-Z][a-z]*", line)
new_line = " ".join(match.group() for match in matches)
```

The variable `new_line` contains:

```py
>>> print(new_line)
'Words Are Sticked Together Here I Need One Space Betweee Them'
```